# apport apache2 segmentation fault

Tags: apache

I'm currently testing image upload on a web application. Each time I upload an image, I get the following error message in `/var/log/apport.log`:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 4849) Wed May 25 11:39:25 2016: called for pid 4798, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 4849) Wed May 25 11:39:25 2016: executable: /usr/sbin/apache2 (command line "/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start")
ERROR: apport (pid 4849) Wed May 25 11:39:25 2016: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 4849) Wed May 25 11:39:25 2016: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_sbin_apache2.0.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
```

`apport-retrace` gives me the following output:

```
[New LWP 3127]
warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/libpq.so.5" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f3e09c86e56 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

I suspect that the problem lies in the `libpq.so.5` library but am not sure. Any tips about how to get gdb to generate more output or links to solutions to similar problems would be appreciated.

UPDATE: stack trace from apport-retrace

```
#0  0x00007f5e1e986e56 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#1  0x00007f5e1e986fec in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#2  0x00007f5e1e79a983 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#3  0x00007f5e1e79a9f5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#4  0x00007f5e1e79b7e1 in file_ms_free () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#5  0x00007f5e1e799af5 in finfo_resource_destructor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#6  0x00007f5e1e9be040 in list_entry_destructor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#7  0x00007f5e1e9bbe81 in zend_hash_del_key_or_index () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#8  0x00007f5e1e9be221 in _zend_list_delete () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#9  0x00007f5e1e99e4d0 in _zval_ptr_dtor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#10 0x00007f5e1e9d0587 in zend_object_std_dtor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#11 0x00007f5e1e9d05b9 in zend_objects_free_object_storage () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#12 0x00007f5e1e9d644c in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#13 0x00007f5e1e9d6473 in zend_objects_store_del_ref () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#14 0x00007f5e1e99e4d0 in _zval_ptr_dtor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#15 0x00007f5e1e9bbf88 in zend_hash_destroy () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#16 0x00007f5e1e9ad3fb in _zval_dtor_func () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#17 0x00007f5e1e99e4d0 in _zval_ptr_dtor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#18 0x00007f5e1e9d0587 in zend_object_std_dtor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#19 0x00007f5e1e9d05b9 in zend_objects_free_object_storage () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#20 0x00007f5e1e9d644c in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#21 0x00007f5e1e9d6473 in zend_objects_store_del_ref () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#22 0x00007f5e1e99e4d0 in _zval_ptr_dtor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#23 0x00007f5e1e9d0587 in zend_object_std_dtor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#24 0x00007f5e1e9d05b9 in zend_objects_free_object_storage () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#25 0x00007f5e1e9d5fb7 in zend_objects_store_free_object_storage () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#26 0x00007f5e1e99ebe3 in shutdown_executor () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#27 0x00007f5e1e9ae3b2 in zend_deactivate () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#28 0x00007f5e1e94e74d in php_request_shutdown () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#29 0x00007f5e1ea5ffaf in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#30 0x00007f5e2314ebe0 in ap_run_handler ()
#31 0x00007f5e2314f129 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#32 0x00007f5e2316418c in ap_internal_redirect ()
#33 0x00007f5e1bf0acfc in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
#34 0x00007f5e2314ebe0 in ap_run_handler ()
#35 0x00007f5e2314f129 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#36 0x00007f5e231646ca in ap_process_async_request ()
#37 0x00007f5e231649a4 in ap_process_request ()
#38 0x00007f5e23161442 in ?? ()
#39 0x00007f5e23158220 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#40 0x00007f5e1f37f767 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#41 0x00007f5e1f37f9a6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#42 0x00007f5e1f37fa06 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#43 0x00007f5e1f3806e0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#44 0x00007f5e231358ae in ap_run_mpm ()
#45 0x00007f5e2312f046 in main ()
```